# Was Dr. Lecter really cooking human flesh?

Tags: plot-explanation, hannibal-tv

In the TV-series [*Hannibal*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2243973/) in one of the episodes we see Dr. Lecter killing a man and there are many incidents throughout the season about Hannibal killing people. But I didn't understand or could not see any reference about Dr. Lecter cooking them. All scenes suggested that he may be cooking a human flesh.

There were some mild humor by Dr. Lecter saying "all are non-vegetarian" or something, I couldn't recall.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? Are you wondering if they are actually frying human flesh for the show? Or are you asking if that is a pretense to Dr. Lecter? If your curiosity is just about Dr. Lecter, the answer would be yes it is human flesh. They do not call him "Hannibal the Cannibal" for nothing. Dr. Lecter is a character created by [Thomas Harris](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0365383/?ref_=tt_ov_wr). This is the character's main trait, other than being a homicidal sociopath.

Comment: @Paulster2 I know they are not cooking actual human flesh duh'. I was wondering like in the movie version we saw that Hannibal was tearing flesh from human and eating them. But in tv-series it was just hinted not being showed. That's the confusion.

Comment: Fair enough, but your question wasn't very clear. Believe me when I say there have been other questions on this SE site which are *just* that stupid, so was making sure. Like I was saying though, since this is Thomas Harris' character, it would be the same as the movie. I haven't seen the TV show, so I'm leaving this here in the comments.

Comment: Something I just thought of ... I bet the reason for the distinct difference is because it's a TV show. While it is definitely an adult theme, they are still limited to what they can show. I mean, they cannot go showing Anthiny Hopkins cutting open Ray Liota's cranium, slicing off the frontal lobe, then making him eat it. Just a little over the top for TV (here in the US anyway). Besides, it has been my experience, movies which leave it to the imagination can be far worse than showing everything ... The movie [Seven](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114369/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) comes to mind.

Comment: "Before we begin, you must all be warned: Nothing here is vegetarian. Bon appétit" - That's what he said.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

Yes he is cooking human flesh. You see it at various points in the show. He has a Rolodex of whose body parts he has kept in his freezer, and chooses certain ones on account of his current mood and dish he is creating. I believe it's shown the most in episode 7 "[Sorbet](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2373037/)". [image][image]